# Process items in queue as the items are added inside a while loop

Tags: java

I have a method where I listen for UDP packets in a while loop. I want to parse the packets using another method in a different class as they arrive and do many different parsing and analyzing of each packet in another part of the application. I am thinking it would be better to have the `PacketParser` methods process the Queue outside of the loop. Would it be possible to just add the packets to a `Queue` as they come in and then have another part of the application listen for items as they come into the Queue and perform other actions as the original while loop keeps listening for packets and adds them to the queue? I would like to have another function monitor the queue and process the packets, is there something in `Java` to monitor a `Queue` or `Stack`? Is there a better way to do this?

```
public void read(String multicastIpAddress, int multicastPortNumber) {
        PacketParser parser = new PacketParser(logger);
        InetAddress multicastAddress = null;
        MulticastSocket multicastSocket = null;
        final int PortNumber = multicastPortNumber;
        try {
            multicastAddress = InetAddress.getByName(multicastIpAddress);
            multicastSocket = new MulticastSocket(PortNumber);
            String hostname = InetAddress.getLocalHost().getHostName();
            byte[] buffer = new byte[8192];
            multicastSocket.joinGroup(multicastAddress);
            System.out.println("Listening from " + hostname + " at " + multicastAddress.getHostName());
            int numberOfPackets = 0;
            while (true) {
                numberOfPackets++;
                DatagramPacket datagramPacket = new DatagramPacket(buffer, buffer.length);
                multicastSocket.receive(datagramPacket);
                // add to queue for another function to process the packets

            }
        } catch (SocketException socketException) {
            System.out.println("Socket exception " + socketException);
        } catch  (IOException exception) {
            System.out.println("Exception " + exception);
        } finally {
            if (multicastSocket != null) {
                try {
                    multicastSocket.leaveGroup(multicastAddress);
                    multicastSocket.close();
                } catch (IOException exception) {
                    System.out.println(exception.toString());
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: I just skimmed through your code and it looks like you have an infinite loop. Maybe try `multi-threading` or `event-handling`?

Comment: I recommend looking into multi threading: use a producer-consumer pattern, and blocking queues for thread safety.

Comment: @Chris I have never heard of a producer-consumer pattern, I'm going to look into it more, I just found a basic article that explains it a little bit and I I think that this pattern will help achieve what I'm trying to do, thanks! https://dzone.com/articles/producer-consumer-pattern

Comment: Sometimes learning the terminology/ patterns is all it takes to spark figuring it out ;)

Comment: @Patrick At the moment I just put an infinite loop until I figure out what logic I want to use to stop the loop. I will look at `event-handling`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, so I did some reading about the producer-consumer pattern and figured it out so here is what I did.

Basically the producer-consumer pattern involves three things: a producer, a consumer and a shared queue. In this context the `PacketReader` is the producer that takes in network packets and places them into the shared queue. The `PacketParser` is the consumer who processes the packets in the shared queue. So I created an instance of a `LinkedBlockingQueue` and passed that shared queue into an instance of the consumer (PacketReader) and an instance of the producer (PacketParser). Then the consumer and producer instances are each passed into an instance of the `Thread` class. Finally, call the `start()` method on each thread instance.

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        BlockingQueue<Packet> queue = new LinkedBlockingQueue<>();
        ILogger logger = Injector.getLogger();

        Thread reader = new Thread(new PacketReader(logger, queue, "239.1.1.1", 49410));
        Thread parser = new Thread(new PacketParser(logger, queue));

        reader.start();
        parser.start();
    }
}
```

The reason to use the `LinkedBlockingQueue` is because the `put()` method will block the queue if full and `take()` will block if queue if empty. The producer and consumer classes need to implement the `Runnable` interface and contain a method named `run()` that takes no parameters.

**Consumer class**

```
public class PacketParser implements Runnable {

    private ILogger logger;
    private BlockingQueue<Packet> queue;
    private boolean running = true;

    public PacketParser(ILogger logger, BlockingQueue<Packet> queue) {
        this.logger = logger;
        this.queue = queue;
    }

    public void stop() {
        running = false;
    }

    public void run() {
        while (running) {
            Packet packet;
            try {
                packet = queue.take();
                parse(packet);
            } catch (InterruptedException exception) {
                logger.Log(exception.getStackTrace().toString());
            }
        }
    }
```

**Producer class**

```
public class PacketReader implements Runnable {

    private ILogger logger;
    private final Queue<Packet> queue;
    private String multicastIpAddress;
    private int multicastPortNumber;
    private boolean running = true;

    public PacketReader(ILogger logger, Queue<Packet> queue, String multicastIpAddress, int multicastPortNumber) {
        this.logger = logger;
        this.queue = queue;
        this.multicastIpAddress = multicastIpAddress;
        this.multicastPortNumber = multicastPortNumber;
    }

    public void stop() {
        running = false;
    }

    public void run() {
        InetAddress multicastAddress = null;
        MulticastSocket multicastSocket = null;
        try {
            multicastAddress = InetAddress.getByName(multicastIpAddress);
            multicastSocket = new MulticastSocket(multicastPortNumber);
            String hostname = InetAddress.getLocalHost().getHostName();
            byte[] buffer = new byte[8192];
            multicastSocket.joinGroup(multicastAddress);
            System.out.println("Listening from " + hostname + " at " + multicastAddress.getHostName());
            int numberOfPackets = 0;

            while (running) {
                numberOfPackets++;
                DatagramPacket datagramPacket = new DatagramPacket(buffer, buffer.length);
                multicastSocket.receive(datagramPacket);
                Packet packet = new Packet(numberOfPackets, datagramPacket);
                queue.add(packet);
            }
        } catch (SocketException socketException) {
            System.out.println("Socket exception " + socketException);
        } catch  (IOException exception) {
            System.out.println("Exception " + exception);
        } finally {
            if (multicastSocket != null) {
                try {
                    multicastSocket.leaveGroup(multicastAddress);
                    multicastSocket.close();
                } catch (IOException exception) {
                    System.out.println(exception.toString());
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```